# Reading a variable from XML

Tags: sql-server

For the sake of simplification, imagine I'm writing a procedure like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[TestXml]
( @Message xml ) -- Passing this '<Test><TransactionID>4</TransactionID></Test>'
as

declare @TransactionID int;
```

How do I now parse the transaction ID, 4, from `@Message` into `@TransactionID`?

I'm expecting something like

```
select @TransactionID = msg.prop.value('@TransactionID', 'int')
       from @Message.nodes('Test') as msg(prop);
```

or

```
select @TransactionID = prop.value('@TransactionID', 'int')
       from @Message.nodes('Test') as msg(prop);
```

but neither of these seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<Test><TransactionID>4</TransactionID></Test>'

DECLARE @TransactionID INT

SELECT @TransactionID = t.p.value('.[1]', 'int')
FROM @XML.nodes('Test') t(p)

SELECT @TransactionID
```

Comment: Oddly, I'd been thinking this doesn't work because Management Studio is underlining it and saying that it couldn't find column p. But, if I run it, it works anyway.

Comment: Now it's saying it can't find column t. But it works either way, if I run it.

Comment: Ok :). I glad to be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Declare @xml xml = '<Test><TransactionID>4</TransactionID></Test>'

select prop.value('.', 'int')
   from @xml.nodes('Test/TransactionID') as msg(prop);
```

Result : `4`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. This works nicely

```
select @TransactionID = @Message.value('/Test[1]/TransactionID[1]', 'int')
```